# How can i change google chart Background color without draw function

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Here. I have basic google chart. I want to change background color of chart.
Its work fine with draw function,
but problem was i need to change only google chart color without rerender with data or draw function.

Like this

```
function changeColor(){
   gchart.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

instead of this.

```
function changeColor(){
   chartOption.backgroundColor='red';
   gChart.draw([somearrayToDataTable], chartOption)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change one of the chart's configuration options and have the chart update,
the only way is to re-draw the chart.

otherwise, you have to manually change the SVG the chart produces,
on the chart's ready event.

in this case, the background color will be set on the chart's main `<rect>` element.
on the ready event, we can use the original color to find the element and change the `'fill'` attribute.

when setting configuration options related to color,
the chart will convert any named colors to HEX values.

'red' = #ff0000

the chart will also convert any HEX values used in the configuration options to lower case.

#FF0000 will become #ff0000

for this to work, we must use a lower case HEX value in our configuration option.
e.g.

```
backgroundColor: '#008000',  // <-- green
```

then in the ready event, we can find the element with that color and change it...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  var rectangles = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('rect');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(rectangles, function(rect) {
    if (rect.getAttribute('fill') === options.backgroundColor) {
      rect.setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');
    }
  });
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y')
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3]
  ]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: '#008000',  // <-- green
    colors: ['#00ffff']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var rectangles = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('rect');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(rectangles, function(rect) {
      if (rect.getAttribute('fill') === options.backgroundColor) {
        rect.setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');  // <-- red
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried but this method is not official, so i moved to high-chartsjs, i am really appreciate your efforts. i am accepting this answer as solved, thanks